# does the series $ \sum _ { n = 0 } ^ \infty \frac 1 { \sqrt n + \ln n } $ converge or diverge? having trouble

Tags: convergence-divergence

> Does the series
> $$ \sum _ { n = 0 } ^ \infty \frac 1 { \sqrt n + \ln n } $$
> converge or diverge?

I believe this is divergent but having a hard time proving it is.

Comment: I don't know about the series, but _we_ diverge from questions where the asker does not show any effort at understanding the problem (and thus our answers).  At a minimum, post the series rather than forcing us to search or download!

Comment: Yeah, please add some more context to this question. This isn't a homework solving service. People are willing to help if you do this though!

Comment: The first term in the series is not defined

Comment: Now it's an easy call.  Hint:  when $n$ is 1000, the term is a lot bigger than $1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
& \sum_{\xcancel{n\, =\, 0}}^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt n + \ln n} \qquad \ln0 \text{ is undefined} \\[8pt]
& \sum_{n\, =\, 1}^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt n + \ln n} \ge \sum_{n\,=\,1}^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt n + \sqrt n} = +\infty.
\end{align}